# JSONField Django template doesn't show me what I went

Tags: python, json, django, postgresql, field

after a lot of research, I still have not found how to do it: my purpose is to be able to separate my json in keys/values to only display what it seems to me necessary (for example the title, the authors, ...). It's a Django Site web.
That I have done :

***In models.py***

```
class Production(models.Model):
    titre = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)
    publis = JSONField()
    def __str__(self):
        return '%s' % (self.titre)
    class Meta:
        db_table = 'Production'
```

***In Views.py***

```
def post_json(request):
    posts = Production.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'appli/post_json.html', {'posts': posts})
```

***And the template : post_json.html ***

This show me fully my json data

```
    {% for post in posts %}
    <div>
        <p>aa = {{ post.publis }}</p>
    </div>
    {% endfor %}
```

And this it's what I'm trying to show only the authors

```
 <h1>Publications lalala</h1>
         {% for post in posts %}
                aa = {{ post.publis }}
            <p> Num : {{ aa.UT }}</p>
            <p>Auteur : {{ aa.AU }} </p>
         {% endfor %}
```

The display on my web page :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C6FVh.png)

Thank you in advance for your help (sorry if there are mistakes of english I am french)

Comment: "my purpose is to be able to separate my json in keys/values to only display what it seems to me necessary" : actually there's nothing like a "json" object  involved - at runtime, `post.publis` is a plain Python dict, so the usually lookup rules apply in your templates (ie : `post.publis.UT` will be resolved as `post.publis["UT"]`).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To access the keys from `post.publis` in the Django template you use the regular dot lookup, e.g. `{{ post.publis.UT }}`.

```
{% for post in posts %}
    <p>Num : {{ post.publis.UT }}</p>
    <p>Auteur : {{ post.publis.AU }} </p>
{% endfor %}
```

Putting `aa = {{ post.publis }}` in your template does not assign `post.publis` to `aa`. If you want to prevent the duplication of `post.publis`, you can use the [`with`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/templates/builtins/#with) tag.

```
{% for post in posts %}
  {% with aa=post.publis %}
    <p>Num : {{ aa.UT }}</p>
    <p>Auteur : {{ aa.AU }} </p>
  {% endwith %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: "To access the keys in the JSON field " : actually at this point it's not a `JSONField` but a plain python dict... (ok, pedantic I guess but at least technically correct - which as we all know is "the best kind of correct" <g>)

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers since the issue was unrelated to the field type, I've removed the mention of JSONField from the answer.

Comment: thank you very much ! I had tried something similar. However, it had not worked before.

Comment: This is good, but what if you don't know the names of the keys and just want to loop `key -> dict[key]` ?

Comment: @Shadur you can loop through the items, e.g. `{% for key, value in mydict.items %}{{ key }}: {{ value }}{% endfor %}`