# How to render an arbitrary set of key->value pairs from a JSONField in a Jinja2 template?

Tags: django, jinja2, django-jsonfield

I'm trying to add debug information to a frontend; for reasons that don't need to be gone into at the moment I'm storing the pertinent information in a JSONField.

Storing and retrieving the information works correctly, but when I try to render it via J2 to the page it's supposed to be at I'm running into some issues.

Here's the segment in question:

```
          {% for log in connection.debug_logs.all %}
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td>{{ log.log_message }}</td>
                <td>
                    {% for key in log.log_data %}
                      {{ key }}: {{ log.log_data.key }} <br/>
                    {% endfor %}
                </td>
            </tr>
          {% endfor %}
```

What I'm *hoping* for is for that to produce a series of lines of `key: value`. What I'm getting *instead* is:

```html
                <td>Login requested by vmx1.internal (11.22.33.44)</td>
                <td>
                      Framed-Route:  <br/>
                      Service-Type:  <br/>
                      Framed-IP-Address:  <br/>
                      Framed-IPv6-Route:  <br/>
                      control:Auth-Type:  <br/>
                      Framed-IPv6-Prefix:  <br/>
                      Delegated-IPv6-Prefix:  <br/>
                      ERX-Egress-Policy-Name:  <br/>
                      ERX-Ingress-Policy-Name:  <br/>
                      ERX-Virtual-Router-Name:  <br/>
                      control:Cleartext-Password:  <br/>
                </td>
```

Using `{{ log.log_data | pprint }}` does yield the keys and values, but renders them as a plaintext JSON string which gets flattened by the html renderer and isn't terribly useful for debugging purposes.

Trying 'log.log_data[key]' instead yields a 'Could not parse the remainder' error.

I've tried the suggestions in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43492271/jsonfield-django-template-doesnt-show-me-what-i-went) as well as [these](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19141073/rendering-a-dictionary-in-jinja2) and a few others that came up during google searches, but none of them seem to address this issue -- all of them are either working with known keys, working with an actual dict instead of a JSONField, or sometimes both.

I'm probably missing something very simple and straightforward, but I've run out of ways to phrase my question in a search engine. Any tips?

**EDIT** No, it is *not* actually a dictionary. I've *also* tried the solutions in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25373154/how-to-iterate-through-a-list-of-dictionaries-in-jinja-template) and that leads back to the `Could not parse the remainder` error.

So the data I'm looking for is absolutely there, I'm just having issues trying to get it to render properly.

**Third and final edit**: The problem was apparently that Django templates are *not quite* Jinja2 templates, and rather than `{% for key, value in log.log_data.items() %}` I needed to use `{% for key, value in log.log_data.items %}`

Comment: `{% for key, value in log.log_data.items() %}` and `{{ key }}: {{ value }}` if it is a dictionary: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25373154/how-to-iterate-through-a-list-of-dictionaries-in-jinja-template

Comment: It's apparently *not* a dictionary. I've tried that one as well and that results in `Could not parse the remainder` errors.

Comment: Turn the json to a dictionary inside your view and pass it to the template. Then change your template as β.εηοιτ.βε recommended above.

Comment: @Tarquinius That sounds useful. Got an example?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to iterate through a list of dictionaries in Jinja template?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25373154/how-to-iterate-through-a-list-of-dictionaries-in-jinja-template)

Comment: @sunderamdubey I'd already seen it, and no, it does not -- getting the Could Not Parse The Remainder error when I try to iterate over it the way β.εηοιτ.βε also suggested.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of hair-tearing, I discovered that Django templates are *not quite* exactly the same as Jinja2 templates.

Specifically, what the J2 documentation told me to write as

```
{% for key, value in log.log_data.items() %}
```

should instead have been

```
{% for key, value in log.log_data.items %}
```

This worked and got me the output I was looking for. I'm leaving this as an answer here in case someone else runs into the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

Do the conversion from json inside your view to have a greater range of utilities than inside the jinja2 template world.

```py
import json
DEBUG_LOGS_JSON = "[
    {"log_data": {"Framed-Route": "route1", "Service-Type": "type1"}, "log_message": "my"},
    {"log_data": {"Framed-Route": "route2", "Service-Type": "type2"}, "log_message": "name"},
    {"log_data": {"Framed-Route": "route3", "Service-Type": "type3"}, "log_message": "Tarquinius"},
]"

def my_view(request):
    my_dict = json.loads(DEBUG_LOGS_JSON)  # instead you could also restructure the data passed to the template here.
    return render("my_template.html", context=my_dict)
```

```html
{% for dictionary in my_dict %}
<tr>
  <td>{{ dictionary.log_message }}</td>
  <td>
    {% for key, value in dictionary.log_data.items() %}
    {{ key }}: {{ value }} <br/>
    {% endfor %}
  </td>
</tr>
{% endfor %}
```

If this does not represent the structure of your json, then please provide an example. Let me know how it goes.

Comment: Ahh, I see where I'm having the communication error. It's not a single view just for the debug info; the view is of the 'Connection' object that can have multiple `debug_log` objects attached, and each `debug_log` object has a `log_data` field that contains the JSON. But I'm gonna see if this gets me any further and let you know.